# How to open new terminal and run script and sent the option

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome

I have two script, "main.sh" will open a new terminal and execute the second script "test.sh".

Is there any method if i run main.sh it will run test.sh, but i don't wish user press any item, i wish it will skip press item, and just jump to press ip address. I wish my item is set to 1, which is ping ip.

main.sh

```
gnome-terminal -x ./test.sh
```

test.sh:

```
echo "1. ping ip "

echo "2. shut down  "
echo "3. reboot           
echo -n"item:"
read $item
echo -n "Please enter ip address 192.168."

read ipaddress
echo "your ip address is:" $ipaddress


if [ "$status" == "1" ]; then

ip="192.168.0.$ipaddress"
ping -c 1 $ip >"pinglog"

ping_ok=`cat "pinglog"| grep Unreachable`

if [ "$ping_ok" == "" ]; then

echo "BMC ip" $ip "==>ping PASS"
else echo "fail"

else if [ "$status" == "2" ]; then

init 0

else if [ "$status" == "3" ]; then

init 6
else


echo "q" 

break

fi
```

Comment: Is this script working as it is? I haven't tested it, but it does not seem like it would work. You want to skip the initial menu, is this right?

Comment: some mistake on the code, but basely i wants to express is i wants to skip some step on the script. If there are many devices about 20, i must manual execute ./test.sh this script, which waste lot of time. I wish i can used main,sh which can help me open multiple terminal and skip the beginning enter which item.

Comment: You are still ignoring good advice from [several questions ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064417/test-ip-is-able-to-ping-but-only-one-loop-it-ended)

Comment: How to close this question?This question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is to modularize this into separate scripts.

Put the menu in `menu.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    cat <<'____HERE'
      1. ping ip
      2. shut down
      3. reboot
____HERE

    read -p "item:" item   # no dollar sign on the variable you read!
    case $item in 
        1) exec bmcping;;
        2) init 0;;
        3) init 6;;
        q) break;;
    esac
done
```

(As noted elsewhere, this would be more elegantly done with `select`, but it will amount to more or less the same code.)

Then put the ping functionality into a separate script -- I called this `bmcping` in the menu above.

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p "Please enter ip address 192.168.0." octet
ip="192.168.0.$octet"
ping -c 1 "$ip" | grep Unreachable &&
  echo "BMC ip" $ip "==>ping PASS" || echo "fail"
```

As stated in a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067497/874188) you'd be better off just examining the exit status from `ping` instead of grepping for a particular error message; there are multiple errors (network unreachable, no route to host, etc) which could cause it to fail, but all of them will result in a non-zero exit code from `ping`.

If you save this in `/home/you/bin/bmcping` and don't have `/home/you/bin` in your `PATH` already, add something like this to your `.bashrc` or similar:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The change will take effect when you start a new shell, or if you do `. ~/.bashrc` at the Bash prompt.

Now, you can call `bmcping` from your `gnome-terminal` script or run it in a loop, like

```
for ((i=1; i<=20; ++i)); do
    echo "$i" | bmcping
done
```

Incidentally, this also illustrates how you could feed input to your current script, so with completely minimal changes, you could feed your current menu a "1" and an IP address; but assuming you want the script to read the IP address interactively, this becomes rather awkward and clunky.  But then, a better design altogether would be to accept an IP address as a command-line argument instead of requiring interactive input.

(I privately wonder why you would want to run each in a separate `gnome-terminal`; a better approach would be to start a number of background processes, and collect their output into a log file.)

Comment: how come it occur  line 11: exec: bmcping: not found

Comment: Because you did not (yet?) create a new script with that name; or it's not on your `PATH`

Comment: i just used this as an example. Actually the purpose of this script is to update bios version. If i have 10 devices, and i wants to update bios. I need to open 10 terminal, which waste alot of time. Instead of waiting, i just figure out a way to used a script and help me open 10 terminal and execute the script Which will be faster, else i have to manual open 10 terminal .  I just used the ping as an example.

Comment: how am i going to add path. i add bmcping this file, but same.

Comment: If it's in the current directory, you can simply use `./bmcping`.  The usual convention is to put personal binaries in `$HOME/bin` and include `PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` in your `.bashrc` or similar if it's not already there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure I understood what you want or that your script works properly, but if you have a menu in the beginning of your script that you're trying to skip in some circumstances, just add a command-line parameter. Since your script does not take any command-line parameter as it is, you could test for the presence of a single specific parameter and act accordingly.

For example, to test for the presence of a `"skipmenu"` string as first parameter, you could do the following on the beginning of your script:

```
if [ "$1" = "skipmenu"]; then
    # menu must be skipped - set up your variables accordingly here
else
    # regular menu
fi

# rest of your code here
```

Executing it as `./test.sh` will bring up your menu as usual, but executing it as `./test.sh skipmenu` will skip it. This way you could do `gnome-terminal -x ./test.sh skipmenu`.

Also, a `select` statement is a nice way of making a menu in shell scripts.